# Updating ListBox With New COM Port Data

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I wish for my `ListBox` to update the old values with new values rather than simply adding more and more lines to the `ListBox` like it does at the moment. However, I'm not sure where to look to implement something that can handle this.

My current code looks like this:

```
private void DisplayText(string rawData)
{
    textArduinoData.Text = rawData;
    string[] sortedData = rawData.Split(';');

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedData.Length; i++)
    {
        listPortData.Items.Add(sortedData[i].ToString());

    }
}
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction to implementing this update feature? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manage the process. It is easy in concept but depending on how much data is needed to be processed, it could get slow quickly. Steps

1. Create a specialized *token* class which implements to `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
2. Have an `ObservableCollection` hold the class items from #1. The observable collection notifies the ListBox when an item is added or removed. This will allow your code to add items one at a time. (*Solves 1 problem*)
3. To solve the next problem of data changing: Have a property named `Text`,  on the class in #1 which will hold the data, provide a property change notification.
4. In the list box bind to the list of items created in step 1 and specify to bind to the `Text`. Use of a data template for the listbox will allow you to bind to the `Text` property of the list's instance.
5. Provide the heuristics/ smarts to read incoming data and find the associated data in the observable collection from step 2. When found change the `Text` property of the existing data to the new and the binding of that list item will change accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment but I ended up getting it to work, using a BindingSource and then using that BindingSource as the DataSource for the ListBox, before I checked this page this morning.

Comment: @CuriousLekgolo First off, regardless I am glad you worked out your issue. Secondly this is still a valid answer and I would not be offended if you mark it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the `ListBox` contains the `string` using the `IndexOf` method and then update the existing `string` (or simply do nothing) or add a new one depending on whether you get an index other than the default value of `-1` back:

```
private void DisplayText(string rawData)
{
    textArduinoData.Text = rawData;
    string[] sortedData = rawData.Split(';');

    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedData.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((index = listPortData.Items.IndexOf(sortedData[i])) == -1)
        {
            listPortData.Items.Add(sortedData[i]);
        }
    }
}
```